# プロジェクトごとにウィンドウを開いたり閉じたりしたい

Tags: emeditor

質問させてください。
例えば A B C D... とたくさんのプロジェクトがあったとしまして、それぞれ別ウィンドウで作業していたとします。
プロジェクト A のウィンドウでは html、js、css ファイルを開き、プロジェクト B のウィンドウでは php、txt ファイルを開いているといった感じです。

「今日は A の作業をするので、A のウィンドウだけ開きたい」「明日は B と C を開く」など、それぞれプロジェクトごとにウィンドウの状態を保存することはできないでしょうか。
ワークスペースがあるのですが、A B のウィンドウを開いた状態で C を開きたいという場合、A B のワークスペースを作り、さらに A B C のワークスペースも作らないといけないと思います。
プロジェクトがどんどん増えていくとワークスペースを保存するのが大変になってしまいます。（例えば B D F を開いているときに K を開きたいとか、その逆で B だけ閉じたいとか）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

説明が下手で申し訳ありません。イメージとしましては VSCode に「Project Manager」という拡張機能があるのですが、それと同じような感じです。
EmEditor でそういったことは可能なのでしょうか・・・
もし解決方法がありましたらご教授いただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: プロジェクトと書かれているので EmEditor のプロジェクト プラグインの事だと理解していますが、これは、1つのグループ ウィンドウのみサポートしています。残念ながら、複数のプロジェクトを同時に開くことはできません。

Comment: そうなのですね、承知しました。ご返信いただきありがとうございます。